# Upload Large File to SP Online in Chunks using Rest API - FinishUpload fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, file-upload, large-file

I was trying to upload the a larger file (500mb) to SharePoint Online document library. I followed the way to upload the file in Chunks with the Article:
[Programmatically Uploading Large Files In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/programmatically-uploading-large-files-in-sharepoint-online)

Startupload and continueupload works well But,  **finishupload(uploadid,offset)** fails at last chunks with an saying:

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPBITSSessionIncompleteException" "The upload was incomplete, Try to save again"**.

I have already tried changing the chunk size 10mb to 100mb but It fails every time at **finishupload**.

The same behavior works fine when I use a CSOM way, following this code:
https://piyushksingh.com/2016/07/22/upload-large-files-to-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use PNP core sdk to upload large file in SharePoint online library.

Use below code to upload large file in SharePoint online library.

```
// Get a reference to a folder
IFolder siteAssetsFolder = await context.Web.Folders.Where(f => f.Name == "SiteAssets").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

// Upload a file by adding it to the folder's files collection, the file will be uploaded in chunks of 10MB
IFile addedFile = await siteAssetsFolder.Files.AddAsync("2gbfile.test", 
                  System.IO.File.OpenRead($".{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}TestFilesFolder{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}2gbfile.test"));
```

Refer this PNP core SDK docs.

[Upload Large file](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/files-large.html)

Comment: I am looking for a JavaScript solutions, which can be used inside my client side application.

Comment: There is a pnp js way to upload the files in chunks, I recently got this solution. https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#adding-files